# how to implement "sticky" variables in terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I'd like to have a Terraform variable with these properties:

- if it has never been set, use a default value
- if no value is provided, use the value from the previous run
- if a value is provided, use that and remember it

The use case is for AWS ECS tags, where I want to be able to deploy a new version by changing the tag, which will cause Terraform to create a new task definition and modify the service definition.  If I run "terraform apply", though, without passing a new value I'd like nothing to happen, i.e., terraform remembers the value from the previous run.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: That’s not really how Terraform works. You are declaring what you want a resource to look like. Change the declaration, the resource follows suit. Change nothing and the resource stays the same, no matter how many times you apply the config.

Answer (score 1):

This document says nothing about maintaining state which is what you need but it does have useful info on variables - https://medium.com/@milescollier/handling-environmental-variables-in-terraform-workspaces-27d0278423df

you can also do -

```
variable "template" {
    type = "string"
    default = "01000000-0000-4000-8000-000030080200"
}

or 

variable "environment-type" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    dev = "DEVELOPMENT"
    preprod = "PRE-PRODUCTION"
    prod = "PRODUCTION"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar and came across this post. Worked out a solution in the end so thought I should share for anyone else coming across this post.

```
variable "maintenance" {
  description = "Set to active, disabled or previous (Default)"
  type        = string
  default     = "previous"
}

# This is used so we can lookup the previous value of the maintenance setting in the state file
data "terraform_remote_state" "bc" {
  backend = "gcs"

  config = {
    bucket = "terraform-bucket"
    prefix = "terraform/state"
  }

  workspace = terraform.workspace

  # Set a default value in case of an empty state file
  defaults = {
    maintenance = "disabled"
  }
}

locals {
  maintenance_status = var.maintenance == "previous" ? data.terraform_remote_state.bc.outputs.maintenance : var.maintenance
}

# Used to expose the current value to subsequent tf runs
output "maintenance" {
  value = example_resource.maintenance.status
}
```

You can then change the setting using the command line, but if not specified it will use the previous value
`terraform apply -var="maintenance=active"`